# Single page site with fixed sidebar navigation

Tags: jquery, scroll, fixed, sidebar

I have been implementing technique for a fixed sidebar on a single page site which can be found here: http://callmenick.com/lab-demos/7-single-page-smooth-scroll/#home

One problem I found though is when you click "Contact", the content window will not be pushed up until the Contact header is only visible. I guess that has to do with the footer making sure there is no additional blank space.

Question is, would it be a hard thing to do to make it so that when you would click "Contact" in the navigation tab, the content window sort of pushes itself upwards so you have the contact header only in a visible area ?

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: The whole source code is here: http://callmenick.com/2013/04/22/single-page-site-with-smooth-scrolling-highlighted-link-and-fixed-navigation/